# Overriden Properties Not Observed

Tags: swift, vector, sprite-kit, overriding

I am creating a game and I created an SKScene subclass that was supposed to serve as the parent for other child classes that will serve as the levels. I initialize the positions and sizer for some blocks within a member variable of the SKScene class, of type [CGPoint]. Later I define a function that actually creates and stores them in another member variable aerialBlocks of type [SKSpriteNode].

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var floatingBlockSize = [CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 10.0)]
    var floatingBlockPositions: [CGPoint] = [CGPointMake(130.0, 70.0)]

    func addPlatforms() {
        var temp = 0
        let holder = floatingBlockPositions
        for _ in floatingBlockPositions {
            floatingBlockPositions[temp].y = floatingBlockPositions[temp].y +  positionsForFirstBlock.y + (groundBlockSize.height / 2)
            let aerialBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "aerialBlock")
            aerialBlock.size = floatingBlockSize[temp]
            aerialBlock.position = floatingBlockPositions[temp]
            print(aerialBlock.position)
            aerialBLockBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: floatingBlockSize[temp])
            temp++
            aerialBlock.physicsBody = aerialBLockBody
            aerialBlock.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            aerialBlock.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = physicsBitMasks.aerialBlock
            aerialBlock.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = physicsBitMasks.player | physicsBitMasks.rollingEnemy | physicsBitMasks.walkingEnemy
            aerialBlock.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = physicsBitMasks.player | physicsBitMasks.rollingEnemy | physicsBitMasks.walkingEnemy
            addChild(aerialBlock)
            aerialBlock.name = "aerialBlock" + String(temp)
            aerialBlocks.append(aerialBlock)
        }
        floatingBlockPositions = holder
    }
}
```

Then in the subclass, I attempt to override both vector parameters, changing both the size and the values stored within.

```
class StreetFight: GameScene {
override var floatingBlockSize: [CGSize] {
        get {
            return [CGSize(width: 50.0, height: 10.0), CGSize(width: 150.0, height: 10.0)]
        }
        set (newValue) {
            newValue
        }
    }
    override var floatingBlockPositions: [CGPoint] {
        get {
            return [CGPointMake(400.0, 70.0), CGPointMake(250.0, 95.0)]
        }
        set (newValue) {
            newValue
        }
    }
}
```

I rely on the parent addPlatforms() method to interpret this new data and place the blocks/platforms accordingly. The platforms, however, are placed far lower than they should be. Switching the SKView displayed in the ViewController, places the one platform in the parent class correctly.